# Add another set of results to an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Not really 100% sure what I am asking here. I want to add another level to an array which I am already looping through.

```
$product_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($product_query)) {$products[] = $row;}
 foreach($products as $product){
  //external array request is here which then generates this:
  foreach ($Items->Item as $Items){
   echo $Items->title; // I want to add these value**s** to the existing $products array
  }
 }
```

So I currently have this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [sku] => TPF1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [sku] => TFL3
        )
```

Am I making sense? Thank you for your help

Stu

Comment: do you want $Items->title to be appended to $product ?

Comment: Yes in as far as lets say there are 3 titles to be added in each existing product.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($product_query)) {$products[] = $row;} 
 foreach($products as &$product) { //notice the ambersand
     foreach ($Items->Item as $Item){ 
        $product['title'] =  $Item->title; 
  } 
}
```

now $products will containt each of the items title

Comment: Does not look like it is formed properly:[5] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 6
            [sku] => TL9
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => title1
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => title2
                )

        )

Comment: is $Item->title an object. can u post the print_r of one $Item

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [title] => title1

Comment: Do I need to convert the xml results to an array?

Comment: will need to use strval($Item->title);